# Can't stop rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I am using an ubuntu machine and the rubymine IDE. The problem is that I am unable to stop the rails server. I tried to stop the server by killing the rails process. But, when I run `pgrep -l rails`, no such process is found. So, I am only able to kill ruby processes, but, the server won't stop.

I tried `./script/server stop` (since I started it by running `./script/server start`), but, that didn't work. Googling around and finding some stackoverflow posts, I tried to change the localhost port's listening port but without success. Could someone help?

Comment: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Comment: @Newben do u want to kill all the process?

Comment: @Sri, yes I want to kill all the process

Comment: @Newben Check my updated answer below and give a try and let me know

Answer (score 355, accepted):

You can use other ports like the following:

```
rails server -p 3001
```

Normally in your terminal you can try `Ctrl + C` to shutdown the server.

The other way to kill the Ruby on Rails default server (which is `WEBrick`) is:

```
kill -INT $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

In your terminal to find out the PID of the process:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, use the number in the PID column to kill the process:

For example:

```
$ kill -9 PID
```

And some of the other answers i found is:

To stop the rails server while it's running, press:

```
CTRL-C
CTRL-Z
```

You will get control back to `bash`. Then type (without the `$`):

```
$ fg
```

And this will go back into the process, and then quit out of `Rails s` properly.

It's a little annoying, but this sure beats killing the process manually. It's not too bad and it's the best I could figure out.

### Updated answer:

You can use `killall -9 rails` to kill all running apps with "`rails`" in the name.

`killall -9 rails`

Comment: Sorry, lsof -wni tcp:3000 returns nothing, and I don't have any tmp/pids/ folder

Comment: If Webrick is running, then its PID is in `{APP_ROOT}/tmp/pids/server.pid` file so you don't have to look for it -- as long as server is running. So, if instead of doing `ctrl-c` you just run that kill command in another terminal, it will kill Webrick server immediately.

Comment: When I run killall -9 rails, I get the message telling 'no such process found ' ??

Comment: Btw, the folder {APP_ROOT}/tmp/pids/exists indeed but it is empty

Comment: try `fuser -n tcp 3000` and kill the process listed if any. Then restart the server..or u can start the server in another port `ruby script/server -p 3001`

Comment: If it's empty then you can start the rails server as you do normally to check... and try to restart the machine once to get the better results... sometimes its will work...

Comment: None of these commands did anything for me. However, rebooting the machine fixed the problem.

Comment: I had to delete (`rm`) the pid file. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24627702/1494454).

Comment: By my, the prosses is called ruby not rails so `killall -9 ruby` did the job

Answer (score 57):

you can use grep command in following way,

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

and then

```
kill -9 {process_id}
```

Comment: in fact, this commnad only catches '0:00 grep --color=auto rails', which I guess is the grep called command...

Comment: Thanks this solution working for server that still run even the terminal force closed. Nice

Comment: And what if I have many processes and I don't want to kill them manually one by one?

Comment: You can kill them all by `killall -9 rails `

Comment: to find the server I had to do `ps aux | grep puma`

Answer (score 33):

`pkill -9 rails` to kill all the process of rails

**Updated answer**

`ps aux|grep 'rails'|grep -v 'grep'|awk '{ print $2 }'|xargs kill -9`

This will kill any running rails process. Replace 'rails' with something else to kill any other processes.

Answer (score 29):

On my MAC the `killall -9 rails` does not work. But `killall -9 ruby` does.

Comment: Same. That's the `COMMAND` value, too.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, on mac as well and in a container

Comment: this is also the only solution on WSL.

Answer (score 22):

Following are steps to kill server process:

`1. lsof -i tcp:3000`

`2. kill -9 1234`

where `1234` is the PID of process: localhost:3000 display in step 1.

OR

Remove file(server.pid) under `Rails.root/tmp/pids/` and restart server.

OR

open app in another port by using command:

`rails s -p 3001`

Answer (score 11):

I generally use:

`killall ruby`

OR

`pkill -9 ruby`

which will kill all ruby related processes that are running like `rails server`, `rails console`, etc.

Comment: If you don't know pkill -9 or kill -9 , it might also be worth to notice that this could kill other ruby processes as well, for example the rubymine IDE.

Answer (score 8):

**1. Simply Delete the pid file from rails app directory**

`Rails_app -> tmp -> pids -> pid file`

Delete the file and run

`rails start`

---

**2. For Rails 5.0 and above, you can use this command**

`rails restart`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a more modern version of Rails and it uses Puma as the web server, you can run the following command to find the stuck Puma process:

```
ps aux | grep puma
```

It will result in output similar to this:

```
85923 100.0  0.8  2682420 131324 s004  R+    2:54pm   3:27.92 puma 3.12.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3010) [my-app]
92463   0.0  0.0  2458404   1976 s008  S+    3:09pm   0:00.00 grep puma
```

You want the process that is not referring to `grep`. In this case, the process ID is 85923.

I can then run the following command to kill that process:

```
kill -9 85923
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `ctrl+c` to shutdown your Webrick Server.

Unfortunately if its not works then forcefully close the terminal and restart it.

Another trick is that

```
1. open your system-monitor(a gui application) on ubuntu

2. Select processes tab 

3. Then look for a process having name 'ruby'

4. End that process
```

Comment: even u restarted sometimes the server is running. Because we need to kill the temp/pid to stop the server

Comment: But normally, terminating the terminal stops the process bcoz its foreground process and runs on terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the server.pid from tmp/pids folder.
In my case, the error was:  A server is already running. Check /home/sbhatta/myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid.

So, I delete server.pid

`rm /home/sbhatta/myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid`
then run `rails s`

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl-Z should normally do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** find what are the items are consuming 3000 port.

```
lsof -i:3000
```

**step 2 :** Find the process named

*For Mac*

```
ruby      TCP localhost:hbci (LISTEN)
```

*For Ubuntu*

```
ruby      TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

**Step 3:** Find the PID of the process and kill it.

```
kill -9 PID
```

Answer (score 3):

it's as simple as

```
pkill -9 ruby
```

nothing more nothing less

Answer (score 2):

I used `killall -9 rails` like Sri suggested and it didn't work. I adjusted the command to `killall -9 ruby` and the server closed immediately.

Tl;dr: `killall -9 ruby`

Answer (score 2):

`killall -9 ruby` will kill all the ruby processes, and at-least on my machine, rails servers appear as ruby processes. `killall -9 rails` is much more specific and doesn't work for older versions of rails servers (it gives a 'rails:no process found' because the process is named ruby)

Encountered this problem a while ago. After submitting a form in activeadmin, the rails server just hanged and I was unable to kill it using normal means (even after ctrl+z it was still running in the background). Learner's answer helped, but this command doesn't need process id.

Answer (score 1):

check the /tmp/tmp/server.pid

there is a pid inside.

Usually, I ill do "kill -9 THE_PID" in the cmd

Comment: I don't have this path, where could it be on an ubuntu machine ?

Comment: it is hidden...go to your app folder,ctrl + H to show your hidden files ,then u able to see it

Answer (score 1):

When the rails server does not start it means that it is already running then you can start by using new port eg.

```
rails s -p 3001
```

or **it starts and stops in that case** you want to **delete temp folder in rails directory structure** it starts the  rails server.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed on Windows (Im using 10 but not sure if the same for oler). If you use cmd.exe and ctrl + c the raisl server stops correctly.

However, if you use Git Bash, it doesn't. It says it has but when you look at the tmp pids, its still there.

Maybe a bug with git bash?

Answer (score 1):

We can kill rails session on Linux using PORT no

```
fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

here 3000 is a port no.
Now restart your server, you will see your server is in running state.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. open your project
2. select in tmp folder
3. select pids folder
4. delete server.pid file
5. now start your rails server

Comment: Didn't work on my rails 5.2 application. `Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)`

Comment: @a.barbieri Then use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768800/10793427

Answer (score 1):

On rails 6 using

`ps aux | grep rails` was not returning the server process

I had to do

`ps aux | grep puma`

to find the actual process and then kill it using

`kill -9 {process_id}`

Answer (score 0):

It is late for this question.
Here is my 2 cents. I made a rake task for stopping the server when I don't have access to it.
I only tested on Mac though.

With this you can simply add it to your project then run the rake command.

Here you go:

Gist link: -latest version will be here.
https://gist.github.com/houmanka/289184ca5d8d92de0499#file-server-rake

Some code in here:

```
# Make a file under: `project_root/lib/tasks/server.rake`

# Then paste the following code

    namespace :server do
      desc "Stop the running server by killing the PID"
      task :kill do
        STDOUT.puts "Enter port number: "
        post_number = STDIN.gets.strip
        system "pid=$(lsof -i:#{post_number.to_i} -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid"
      end
    end

# Then to use it in the terminal: `rake server:kill`
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, Make sure that you are doing command Cntrl+C in the same terminal (tab) which is used to start the server.

In my case, I had 2 tabs but i forgot to stop the server from correct tab and i was wondering why Cntrl+C is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One super easy way would be

`gem install shutup`

then go in the current folder of your rails project and run

`shutup` # this will kill the Rails process currently running

You can use the command 'shutup' every time you want

DICLAIMER: I am the creator of this gem

NOTE: if you are using rvm install the gem globally

```
rvm @global do gem install shutup
```

Answer (score 0):

For my windows 10 machine, <kbd>Ctrl - C</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl - D</kbd> works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just open the file using the location given
   `sudo vi /Users/user1/go/src/github.com/rails_app/rails_project/tmp/pids/server.pid`
2. find the process_id / thread_id at which the process is runnning.
3. Kill the specified process / thread using `kill -9  84699`

Answer (score -2):

Press Ctrl - C it will stop
if not check